# WSO2AM - Pass request IP to backend

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager

I have a RESTful Web Service. Its endpoints need the request IP. I used bellow function to get request IP.

```
String callerIpAddress = "";
String xForwardedForHeader = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if (xForwardedForHeader == null) {  
    callerIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
}
```

If I run these endpoints directly, variable callerIpAddress show exactly request IP.

But when I publish it via WSO2 AM. callerIpAddress show only value: 127.0.0.1.

I used a sequence in In Flow on WSO2 AM, but the results are still the same

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="get-real-ip-json-input">

<property name="X-Forwarded-For" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
<log level="custom">
   <property name="Actual Remote Address " expression="get-property('X-Forwarded-For')"/>
</log>
</sequence>
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file `global_ext.xml` into
`<APIM_HOM>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences` (API_HOME is your home directory of WSO2AM such as `/opt/WSO2AM-vername`) which will have following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
   <filter source="get-property('transport','X-Forwarded-For')" regex=".*">
      <then>
         <property name="coming-X-Forwarded-For"
                   expression="fn:concat(get-property('transport','X-Forwarded-For'), ', ')"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="clientIP" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
         <property name="X-Forwarded-For"
                   expression="fn:concat(get-property('axis2','coming-X-Forwarded-For'), get-property('clientIP'))"
                   scope="transport"
                   type="STRING"/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <property name="X-Forwarded-For"
                   expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"
                   scope="transport"
                   type="STRING"/>
      </else>
   </filter>
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="client_ip_address"
                expression="get-property('transport','X-Forwarded-For')"/>
   </log>
</sequence>
```

Sometimes restart of wso2-am is required once you added new sequence.

In your REST webservice, you can have a function which will return IP address such as:

```
private String getSourceIp() {
    if (request!= null && request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For") != null) {
      return request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    } else {
      return "0.0.0.0"; //or you can throw an error depending on how you want to handle it.
    }
  }
```